# После выхода из сна отключаются колонки

Tags: linux, ubuntu

На ноутбуке Xiaomi Pro 15 стоит Ubuntu 20.10 и оболочка [Unity](https://ubuntuunity.org/), если ноутбук уходит в сон и при этом не подключено зарядное устройство, то после включения ноутбука не работают колонки

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`powertop`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перевел все по возможности в `Bad`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поставьте программу `powertop` вроде бы командой `apt-get install powertop` . Запустите её в терминале с правами из под рута и сделайте скриншот последней вкладки этой программы.

Comment: Добалю в вопрос

Comment: После просыпания если передернуть выход в настройках звука - звук появляется?

Comment: @ГеоргийМорочев, извиняюсь, добавьте в вопрос еще предпоследнюю вкладку Tunables

Comment: @DiD добавил в вопрос

Comment: @eri у меня только одно звуковое устройство, переключиться невозможно

Comment: @ГеоргийМорочев установите все настройки Tunables на значение `Bad`, перезагрузите компьютер, еще раз посмотрите Tunables что все на значении `Bad`. Потом попробуйте уйти в сон. Вернувшись посмотрите, работает ли звук. А потом можно разбираться

Comment: @ГеоргийМорочев попробуйте выполнить команду `/usr/bin/pasuspender /bin/true` после пробуждения из сна, если она поможет, надо будет её прописать кое-куда

Comment: @DiD перевел все по возможности в `Bad`, скрин в вопросе

Comment: После перезагрузки все было опять как на первом скрине данной вкладки

Comment: @DiD выполнил команду
`sudo /usr/bin/pasuspender /bin/true
[sudo] password for geo: 
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Invalid argument`

Comment: @ГеоргийМорочев, команду надо было без sudo набрать. у root нету прав на подключение к PulseAudio.

Comment: @DiD выполнил без sudo без резльтата

Comment: `pluseaudio -k` и потом `pulseaudio --start` как я понял тоже не помогают, значит проблемы с драйверами, надо смотреть весь `dmesg` от рестарта компьютера до загрузки терминала. Отдельно с уходом в сон и пробуждением.

Comment: @DiD может это быть из-за кривой сборки на https://ubuntuunity.org/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удаляем звуковую карту

`echo 1 | sudo tee -a '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.3/remove'`

Где `0000:00:1f.3` это отсюда

```
$ lspci -D|grep Audio
0000:00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
```

Добавляем звуковую карту

`echo 1 | sudo tee -a /sys/bus/pci/rescan`

Можно все обернуть в скрит и положить в `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/sound`